# compute quadratic risk bayesian statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

[image]

I don't understand how can we move from the line 1 to line 2 and 3.
The mean $\bar X_n$ following $\theta$ distribution is for me just $\bar X_n$ but it seems to be another thing here

Comment: Lines 1 to 2 is just taking the constant $\frac1{(b+n)^2}$ outside the expectation and rewriting $((b+n)\theta-(a+n\bar{X}_n))^2$ inside the expectation. It is missing an "("  after the "["

Comment: Lines 2 to 3 seems to use $\mathbb E_\theta[\bar{X}_n]=\theta$, so presumably $\theta$ is the mean of the $X_i$.  Line 3 to 4 seems to use $n\text{Var}_\theta(\bar{X}_n)=\theta$ so presumably $\theta$ is also the variance of the $X_i$.  Do the $X_i$ have iid Poison distributions?

Comment: yes it is thank you but what i Don't get is why $\mathbb E_\theta[\bar{X}_n]=\theta$ ? this mean is Under the $theta$ distribution and not the $bar X_n$

Comment: I would assume $\theta$ is a unknown parameter and  $\mathbb E_\theta[\bar{X}_n]$ here is supposed to represent $\mathbb E[\bar{X}_n\mid \theta]$.  It is then $\mathbb E\left[\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\mid \theta\right] = \frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb E\left[ X_i\mid \theta\right] =  \frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\theta =\theta$